# Sorting in TitanDB with Gremlin

Tags: java, cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

***Each vertices and edges has following properties:***

```
Request [req_id: long, submit_time:long, priority:int, status:char]  
Test_B [tb_id: long, tb_name: string]  
TestSuite [suite_id: long, Suite_Status: char]  
Edge-A [sequence_num: int]  
Edge-B [ sequence_num: int, suite_status: char]
```

***Relationship between vertices and edges:***

```
Request----EdgeA----Test-B  
Request----EdgeB----TestSuite  
TestSuite----EdgeC----Test-B
```

Below query is ordering(submit_time from request) in ascending order and will display the TestSuite details:

```
g.V().order().by("submit_time",incr).outE("Edge-B").
  has("suite_status","Q").inV().valueMap()
```

Here is an example graph:

```
rj1=graph.addVertex(label,"request","req_id",1138,"status","S","priority",3,"submit_time",1330647978000)
rj2=graph.addVertex(label,"request","req_id",1133,"status","S","priority",2,"submit_time",1330662012000)
rj3=graph.addVertex(label,"request","req_id",1136,"status","S","priority",1,"submit_time",1330652298000)
rj4=graph.addVertex(label,"request","req_id",1135,"status","S","priority",1,"submit_time",1330666768000)

ts1=graph.addVertex(label,"test_suite","test_suite_id",8713)
ts2=graph.addVertex(label,"test_suite","test_suite_id",8718)
ts3=graph.addVertex(label,"test_suite","test_suite_id",8688)
ts4=graph.addVertex(label,"test_suite","test_suite_id",8729)

tb1=graph.addVertex(label,"test_b","tb_id",574)
tb2=graph.addVertex(label,"test_b","tb_id",573)
tb3=graph.addVertex(label,"test_b","tb_id",577)


e1=rj1.addEdge("edgeB",ts1,"sequence",1,"job_suite_status","Q")
e2=rj1.addEdge("edgeB",ts2,"sequence",2,"job_suite_status","Q")
e1=rj2.addEdge("edgeB",ts1,"sequence",1,"job_suite_status","Q")
e2=rj2.addEdge("edgeB",ts3,"sequence",2,"job_suite_status","Q")
e1=rj3.addEdge("edgeB",ts4,"sequence",1,"job_suite_status","Q")
e2=rj3.addEdge("edgeB",ts2,"sequence",2,"job_suite_status","Q")
e1=rj4.addEdge("edgeB",ts3,"sequence",1,"job_suite_status","Q")
e2=rj4.addEdge("edgeB",ts4,"sequence",2,"job_suite_status","Q")

e1=rj1.addEdge("edgeA",tb1,"sequence",1)
e2=rj1.addEdge("edgeA",tb2,"sequence",2)
e3=rj2.addEdge("edgeA",tb1,"sequence",1)
e4=rj2.addEdge("edgeA",tb1,"sequence",2)
e5=rj3.addEdge("edgeA",tb2,"sequence",1)
e6=rj3.addEdge("edgeA",tb3,"sequence",2)
e7=rj4.addEdge("edgeA",tb3,"sequence",2)
e8=rj4.addEdge("edgeA",tb1,"sequence",1)
```

Here, rj1, rj2, rj4 is connected to tb1(edgeA):
so for each test_b (example: tb_id=574), sort request(rj1,rj2,rj4) based on submit_time and take test_suite_id and sequence.

Finally I need to print ***test_suite_id, sequence, and corresponding req_id***. Kindly help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: can you please provide an example of some nodes and the expected result?

Comment: @cattani I have updated the question with sample data..can you please help me on this.

Comment: that traversal doesn't seem to work with your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to label steps with `as()` and then use `select()` to prepare the result.

```
g.V().has("tb_id", 574).
  in("edgeA").dedup().as("r").
  order().by("submit_time", Order.incr).as("st").
  outE("edgeB").has("job_suite_status", "Q").as("s").
  inV().as("t").
  select("t", "s", "r", "st").
    by("test_suite_id").by("sequence").by("req_id").by("submit_time")
```

Start from the test with tb_id 574, then traverse to its requests (label as `r`), order the requests by submit time (label as `st`), traverse to the sequences (label as `s`), finally traverse to the test suites (label as `t`).

Use `select()` to prepare the result output and `by()` to pick the properties: test suite, sequence, request, and submit time.